# Is there a "pg_restore --quiet" option like "psql --quiet"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psql, pg-restore

`psql` has a `-q` / `--quiet` option (environment variable `QUIET`).  `pg_restore` does not have a quiet option.  Is there any way to make `pg_restore` not verbosely show the SQL commands that it's executing?

```
# e.g., here's the verbose output that I don't want to see:
$ pg_restore --cluster 8.4/mycluster mycluster.dump
---- PostgreSQL database dump
--
SET statement_timeout = 0;SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;SET check_function_bodies = false;
...
--
-- Name: data_src; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace:--
CREATE TABLE data_src (
...
```

Comment: Why don't you simple redirect the output to `/dev/nul`?

Comment: I don't want to redirect output to /dev/null because I don't want to lose any potential error messages.  They would likely go to stderr, so I could just redirect stdout to /dev/null, but I like the idea of something like --quiet better.  I don't mind seeing some informational output, but not every sql command.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The question seems to imply that `pg_restore` is executing these SQL commands and you wouldn't want to see them in the output. But outputting them is what it's only supposed to do.

`pg_restore` has two modes of operation, with or without connecting to a database. When it's called without a database (`-d` option) as shown in the question:

> $ pg_restore --cluster 8.4/mycluster mycluster.dump

then its sole purpose is to output a set of SQL commands in plain text that should be fed to an SQL interpreter to restore the database. Those SQL commands form a coherent set without any concept of verbosity, and they are **not executed** by `pg_restore` itself. They're generally redirected into a file for later execution or piped into `psql` for immediate execution.

Comment: Aha, now it's all clear!  I was mistakenly assuming that without -d, pg_restore would automatically create the database for me.  But with your explanation, and with reading the pg_restore(1) man page, it's clear now.  My question as a mistaken assumption, so I'll think about how to reword it to make it more clear for future readers. Thanks @Daniel_Vérité!

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect stdout to a file:

```
pg_restore --cluster 8.4/mycluster mycluster.dump > pg_restore.log
```

Or provide the -d option, but what you want is either `-f` or `-d`

```
pg_restore -f pg_restore.sql --cluster 8.4/mycluster mycluster.dump
pg_restore -d yourdatabase --cluster 8.4/mycluster mycluster.dump
```